# @PreAuthorize always throw AccessDenieException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have enabled the @PreAuthorize by @EnableWebSecurity and 
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true, securedEnabled=true) but still i am getting the AccessDeniedException.

My Token is :

```html
{
  "aud": [
"all-app",
  ],
  "user_name": "XYZ",
  "scope": [
"openid"
  ],
  "exp": 1577299332,
  "userid": 1,
  "authorities": [
"ROLE_USER"
  ],
  "jti": "b40960c9-2325-456a-b631-53ca2ccf33e2",
  "client_id": "XYZ"
}
```

My Controller code is given below :

```html
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@GetMapping(value="test") 
public String test() {
       return "SUCCESS"; 
}
```

Comment: `hasRole` should be `USER`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider why it should be USER and in the token is `"authorities": [
"ROLE_USER"
  ]` ?

Comment: Did you try with `jsr250Enabled = true` ? or try to replace `@PreAhorize` with `@Secured("ROLE_USER")` , The @RoleAllowed annotation is the JSR-250’s equivalent annotation of the @Secured annotation so you can try with too

Comment: Because `hasAuthority` takes an authority. `hasRole` takes a **role**. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-granted-authority-vs-role. @TinyOS. Your suggestions are random guesses - trying stuff and seeing what sticks is not a good debugging strategy.

Comment: Ok! in the token he has `authorities` that's why he should replace `hasRole`  with `hasAuthority`. Good point ! thanks @BoristheSpider

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have tried hasAuthority  also, still i am getting the same exception.